# Why does this function call fail?

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie question...
This works fine:

```
function draw() {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
        // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
        var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't display anything:

```
    function draw() {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
        // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
        var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        drawface();
    }
}   

    function drawface() {
        context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }
```

What have I missed?

Thanks very much all below for your answers - and your patience with this silly error!

Answer (score 3):

`context` is defined within the `draw` function. `drawface` does not get the reference. Either pass it in the function, or declare it outside of the function scope.

```
var context = blah;

function draw(){};
function drawface(){};
```

alternative way:

```
function drawface(context) {
    context.blah = foo;
}
```

also, make sure this code executes after DOM ready or script is before end body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `context` locally:

```
var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
```

It's not visible in your `drawface` function, you need to pass it as a parameter:

```
 var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
 drawface(context);


function drawface(context) {
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    ...
```

You may want to read a bit about that at MDC:
[var Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
[Functions and Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass context into the drawface function.

```
function draw() {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
        // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
        var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        drawface(context);
    }
}   
function drawface(context) {
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`context` within the `draw` function is limited in scope to the `draw` function and is not the same as the global reference to `context` in `drawface`.

Making context global by defining it outside of draw, should work::

```
var context;

function draw() {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
        // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
        context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        drawface();
    }
}   

    function drawface() {
        context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }
```